# How to disable code cell view in VSCode Clojure when using LiveShare?

Tags: visual-studio-code, view, clojure, cell

I have this problem that when I join a session using Live-share in VSCode to work on a shared code, I see codes in cells and every function is in a different cell as shown below :

[image]

We are using Clojure language and Calva too and I want to be able to disable this cell view and have the normal code view.
Thanks

Comment: This is a known open issue: https://github.com/BetterThanTomorrow/calva/issues/1850.

As a temporary workaround you can either downgrade your Calva version to before notebooks were introduced (eg. `v2.0.291`) or install a custom visx with notebooks disabled: https://github.com/BetterThanTomorrow/calva/pull/1894